# Getting image from listview onclicklistener

Tags: android, listview, imageview, onclicklistener

I'm a beginner trying to make a simple music player app for a class and I have my listview and onclicklistener working great and everything but I can't figure out how to extract the imageview drawable image from the clicked listview item and display that image on my other activity for a "now playing" type thing.

Why doesn't this work?

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
        long id) {
        Object listItem = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NowPlaying.class));
        long artView = listView.getItemIdAtPosition(0);
        ImageView nowPlayingArt = 
       (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.now_playing_image);
        nowPlayingArt.setImageDrawable(artView);
```

Comment: please post full code and write the question properly to be understandable.

Comment: in your adapter just call `view.setTag(your_image_id)`. Then in `onItemClick` get your_image_id via  `view.getTag()`;

Comment: I have several different images for different views in the listview, so I need to be able to get the image from the specific view that was clicked in the list

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bitmap of your ImageView, stream it to a byteArray and put it as extra to your Intent:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
    ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.now_playing_image);

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NowPlaying.class);
    intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in NowPlaying you have to get the byteArray back from the Intent, decode it to a bitmap and set the bitmap to your ImageView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_now_playing);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("picture");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```